# Help simplifying equation involving radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The question is in regards to this equation:

1. $$\left(\frac{\sqrt3+1}{1+\sqrt3+\sqrt{t}}+\frac{\sqrt3-1}{1-\sqrt3+\sqrt{t}}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{t}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{t}+2}\right)$$

From what I have from trying to simplify is the following:

2. $$\frac{(\sqrt3+1)(1-\sqrt3+\sqrt{t})+(\sqrt3-1)(1+\sqrt3+\sqrt{t})}{(1+\sqrt3+\sqrt{t})(1-\sqrt3+\sqrt{t})}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t}(\sqrt{t}+2)-2}{\sqrt{t}+2}\right)$$

expanded; it simplifies to:

3. $$\frac{2\sqrt{3t}}{-2+2\sqrt{t}+t}\cdot\frac{t+2\sqrt{t}-2}{\sqrt{t}+2}$$

then $${-2+2\sqrt{t}+t}$$ cancels, leaving:

my answer to be:

4. $$\frac{2\sqrt{3t}}{\sqrt{t}+2}$$

But the answer, according to my teacher, is
$$t=4.$$

My question is how?

I have tried to multiply my answer by the conjugate but to no avail.
Do you have any tips or tricks to help me?

Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You refer to an equation at the top of your question, but I only see an expression.  Is that expression supposed to be equal to zero?

Comment: on the worksheet, it just says to simplify. But from the answer that my teacher gave (t=4), i'm not 100% clear on whether or not it is supposed to be equal to zero.

Comment: Your answer is correct according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+((sqrt(3)%2B1)%2F(1%2Bsqrt(3)%2Bsqrt(t))%2B(sqrt(3)-1)%2F(1-sqrt(3)%2Bsqrt(t)))*(sqrt(t)-2%2F(sqrt(t)%2B2))). But as the other commenter mentioned there is no equation. Please ask the person who gave this problem to you.